# How to get an activity on onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment, two activities use it, inside the fragment I have a button that must do something depending on the activity in which it is, but I can not get the activity in the onclicklistener. How should I do this?
It only occurred to me to make a switch, but I do not know what to put in the cases

```
buttonFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
   Activity activity=getActivity();
              switch (activity){
                case ?:{
                   //code activity1
                    break;
                }
                case ?:{
                    //code activity2
                   break;
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  are inside a fragment and you have to get the current activity, you should use `getActivity()`, but in your case this `switch` statement will not work because it accept only numbers, so you have to change your implementation to this:

```
buttonFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(getActivity() instanceof YourActivity1){
            //Do your stuff here for Activity 1
        }

         if(getActivity() instanceof YourActivity2){
              //Do your stuff here for Activity 2
        }
    });
```

Comment: And in the cases they should put?

Comment: Please post the code where you call your fragment to let me make an answer. Thnaks!

Comment: Sorry I dropped the ball, the message was for @petereyn

Comment: A more acceptable solution is to use an interface in fragment and implement it in both activities

Comment: why? it doesnt change anything.